# Flex 3: Possible to call child function from within parent?

Tags: apache-flex, parent-child

Is it possible to call a child function from within the parent?  I know to go child > parent, you can do parentApplication.functionName(parameters);, but what about going the other way... that is parent > child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a component should have specific references to it's children:

```
myChild.function(functionArguments);
```

The function needs to public, though.  I don't recommend calling methods in the parent from the child, though.  That is a break of encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to change the child function to public

Comment: @brds if I provided the solution to your problem; why is the other answer checked?

Answer (score 0):

Ever heard of using an id? or a data structure to store the child?

Also, it should be noted that doing parentApplication.functionName is a very bad coding practice.

Comment: i have a repeater with an ID of "block" to create the children.  I tried doing block[i].init(), but it didn't work.  Also, how should a parent function be called if parentApplication.functionName is bad practice?

Comment: Don't use repeaters if possible, either code the creation of your children manually or use a List or some other kind of data container.  If you want your child, do `block.getChildAt(i)`.  parentApplication.functionName is bad practice because it assumes your application will always have that function, even if there's no way to know that specifically.  You also remove the possibility of reusing said component in another project/application. You're breaking the encapsulation and creating dependencies where it isn't needed. You should be using bubbling events for child->parent communication.